# After upgrading scala (specs2) to newest stable version ibatis started to throw exceptions in test

Tags: scala, jdbc, mybatis, ibatis, specs2

Ive recently have upgraded my scala (i upgraded specs2,scala-compiler, library and got rid off specs). After some issues I finally was able to run my test, but unfortunetly almost all of them (the ones that connect to DB) are throwing the same exception

> service.dao.DaoException:
>   com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:
>   --- The error occurred in dao/sql/Bean(some bean name)_SqlMap.xml.
>   --- The error occurred while applying a parameter map.
>   --- Check the bean.insert-InlineParameterMap.
>   --- Check the statement (update failed).
>   --- Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException:
>   Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

I have ibatis-2.3.4. I know that there is not longer ibatis, but myBatis. Anyway I was wondering what can cause that exception? Before upgrade my tests were fine. Does newest specs2 (basicly newest scala) can't cooperate with sad old ibatis? Do I have to upgrade my ibatis also to myBatis? If I have to,to which version will I upgrade? I also notice that theres somethink like myBatis-scala. Note that I'm using scala only for tests, rest of my project is written in Java 1.6 and its also using ibatis.

Comment: The problem can be many things. I would advise to write the minimal spec reproducing it and: 1. take the same code and execute it as a Scala application (to rule out specs2 issues) 2. take the setup code and place it entirely in the test (to see if there are initialisation issues)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding `sequantial`.